# Finder in a JTable in Java

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I have a program that connects me to a database and shows me all the information in a JTable.
[image]

The problem is that I want to put a search engine because there will be many names in the table, I already looked for similar examples and I have tried to connect them to mine but I have not been able, that is why I ask for your help

```
    public Consulta() {
    initComponents();
    user = Start.user;

    setSize(600, 300);
    setTitle("Sesion de " + user);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);    

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    
    try {

        //TextField name: txtSearch
        //Button name: btnSearch

        Connection cn = Conexion.conectar();
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select Nombre from justname");

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        jTable_usuarios = new JTable(model);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable_usuarios);

        model.addColumn(" ");

        while (rs.next()) {

            Object[] fila = new Object[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                fila[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1); //el primer indice en rs es 1 por eso se suma 1
            }

            model.addRow(fila); //se agrega la fila que encontramos dentro de model

        }

        //cerrar conexion
        cn.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al llenar la tabla. " + e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al mostrar informacion, ¡Contacte al administrador¡");
    }
    }
```

Any advice, comment, suggestion on how I can do it, believe me I will be very grateful.

Comment: That doesn't look like a table to me. A JTable has rows and columns. Looks to me like your table should have 5 columns. If you are treating all 5 columns as a single string then you don't have a very effective database. Each column of data should be a separate column in your database. In any case to search a column for data check our the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a complete working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to search (buscar), not to filter. 
Search in the selected column, starting in row below selected row. Just traverse the table model until you find the searched value and then select that row. Example for the `ActionListener` for the button:

```
    button.addActionListener(this::searchAction);
```

```
private void searchAction(ActionEvent ev) {
    var text = field.getText();    // text to search
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    var col = max(0, table.getSelectedColumn());    // 0 if no column selected
    var row = max(0, table.getSelectedRow());       // 0 if no row selected
    IntStream.concat(
        IntStream.range(row+1, model.getRowCount()),   // search after current row
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, row))                 // then from row 0 up to current
    .filter(i -> (String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i, col)).contains(text)))  // value contains search text?
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(i -> table.changeSelection(i, col, false, false));
}
```

this is just the basic idea, can/should be improved (use regular expression instead of contains, better handling of `null`, search in all columns, empty table, model/view mapping...).

---

Instead of streams, a *normal* `for` loop can be used:

```
private void searchAction(ActionEvent ev) {
    var text = field.getText();
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    var col = max(0, table.getSelectedColumn());
    var row = max(0, table.getSelectedRow());
    for (var i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        var j = (i + row + 1) % model.getRowCount();
        if (String.valueOf(model.getValueAt(j, col)).contains(text)) {
            table.changeSelection(j, col, false, false);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var col = max(0, table.getSelectedColumn());    // 0 if no column selected
 var row = max(0, table.getSelectedRow());       // 0 if no row selected                              
these lines mark me an error
Both 'var' and both 'getSelected'. What should I put there? (Sorry, I'm not that good ... I'm starting, thanks for answering me)

Comment: The var is fixed, thanks.
But I still get an error on the same line but the word 'getSelectedColumn', 'getSelectedRow' and even down 'changeSelection'

Comment: Omg it worked, thanks brother, you don't know how much I appreciate it. You are good, I have another new question, do you think you can help me? xd I'll ask a new question